# Difference between two class member declaration and initialization

Tags: java, initialization, declaration, class-members

What is the exact difference between following kinds of class member declaration and initialization?

**Option 1:**

```
public class MyClass {
    private int myInt = 1;
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
public class MyClass {
    private int myInt;
    {
        myInt = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: No deference........................

Comment: It will make a difference if the variable is `final`.

Comment: @Holger can you show me what you exactly mean? Which difference it will make?

Comment: @d3rbastl3r: [I added an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25379308/2711488)

Answer (score 2):

In the case of

```
public class MyClass {
    private int myInt;
    {
        myInt = 1;
    }
}
```

The *instance initialization block* runs before the constructor *each time* you construct an object.

In the second case, it's the same :)

Conclusion: No difference (but it worth knowing what happens when you construct an object).

See the [docs - Initializing Instance Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html):

> The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor.
>   Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between
>   multiple constructors.

Note that you can decompile *class* files using `javap -c` and verify that.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is syntactic.   For most cases the first form is more readable and straight forward to work with.  The second form can be more powerful as it separates declaration and initialization but given this exact example the compiler will generate exactly the same byte codes.  This is because the compiler will place field initialisers and init blocks into every constructor.  In more complex cases you will find that the ordering between the two approaches can vary;  which is a subtle area that is best avoided as it can cause surprise NullPointerExceptions.

To convince yourself of this, one can use javap -c to decompile the generated class files.

For the first version we get

```
public class A {
  public A();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0       
       5: iconst_1      
       6: putfield      #2                  // Field myInt:I
       9: return        
}
```

and for the second version we get

```
public class B {
  public B();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0       
       5: iconst_1      
       6: putfield      #2                  // Field myInt:I
       9: return        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you are declaring as well ass initializing the member `myInt`
In the second case, you the doing the tasks in two statements. Adding a pair of braces doesn't really make any difference in this context.

**assignment**: throwing away the old value of a variable and replacing it with a new one. Like :

```
myInt = 8;
```

**initialization**: it's a special kind of assignment: the first. Before initialization objects have null value and primitive types have default values such as 0 or false.(**Can be done in conjunction with declaration, as you have done in the first case**) like :

```
private int myInt = 1; //both together
```

**declaration**: a declaration states the type of a variable, along with its name. A variable can be declared only once. It is used by the compiler to help programmers avoid mistakes such as assigning string values to integer variables. Before reading or assigning a variable, that variable must have been declared. Like :

```
private int myint;
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

It will make a difference, if the variable is declared `final`. If a `final` variable is immediately assigned at declaration with a compile-time constant, the variable will be a compile-time constant as well. This means, its value will be copied at compile time rather than read at runtime whenever the variable is accessed and it may appear at places, where only compile-time constants are allowed:

Just for illustration:

```
public class MyClass {
  private final int myInt = 1;
  private final int myIntPlusOne = myInt + 1;// adding two constants

  public MyClass(int parameter) {
    switch(parameter)
    {
      case myInt: // using a name for 1
      case myIntPlusOne: // and for 2
    }
  }
}
```

This does not work if you change `final int myInt = 1` to `final int myInt; { myInt = 1; }`.

The exact specification is found in the [Java Language Specification §4.12.4. final Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

> A constant variable is a final variable of primitive type or type String that is initialized with a constant expression ([§15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)).

For non-`final` variables, it makes no difference.

Comment: @Chris K: this has nothing to do with optimizations, it’s a *requirement* that affect binary compatibility. If you change the value of such a variable without recompiling all classes that inlined the value, you will get surprising results. Further, when modifying such a field via Reflection, most code using the variable won’t notice.

Comment: @Chris K: I reworded it to avoid the word “inline”.

Answer (score 0):

There is no deference, but it could hold your code cleaner.
keep in mind that the

```
{

}
```

have nothing to do with the int!